# Absolutely convergent Dirichlet series with any given infinite number of roots

Tags: dirichlet-series

Suppose that $S = \{\rho_{j} \}$ is any sequence of complex numbers such that
$0 < \text{Re}(\rho_{j}) < 1$, $|\rho_{j}| \to \infty$ as j goes to infinity.

Then, can we construct a Dirichlet series $D(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}n^{-s}$ which converges absolutely for $\text{Re}(s) > 1$,
analytic for $\text{Re}(s) > 0$, and 
\[
D(\rho_{j}) = 0
\]
for all $j$?

If the given sequence $S$ is finite, then this is very easy; just put
\[
D(s) = \prod_{j \leq N}(1 - A^{-s + \rho_{j}})
\]
for some positive integer $A$, and this expands into some Dirichlet polynomial.

But due to some data, I think the infinite case can't be possible.

Is there any result on this topic?

Thank you all.

Comment: You mean $\prod_j (1-A^{\rho_j-s})$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes.

Comment: I am actually interested in the case $0 < \Re(\rho_{j}) < 1$.

Comment: If $\Re(\rho_j)\to \infty$ there is no solution since $F(s) \sim A n^{-s}$ for some $n$ as $\Re(s) \to \infty$

Comment: If you don't care it has many other zeros, take a (locally) analytic function $f(z)$ with zeros at $2^{-\rho}$ and set $F(s) = f(2^{-s})$

Comment: Where is a Dirichlet series?